# Architecture : Microservices file upload , Service vs Facade

Tags: architecture, microservices

I have a microservice architecture with few services and a facade layer on top of it.

Now I want to add the file upload functionality to it.
So basically I will have one microservice for it, whose responsibility is to upload files to a local server, create different versions of image

I have few questions regarding the architecture  : 
a) File upload call : From where this call should get triggered ,  Facade or Individual microservice

b)  Validations / Security : Where should all the validations be present, Calling Service or File upload service (As per me the file upload service)

c) Is there a defined pattern for file upload.

Comment: You are asking about uploads, but do you know how you are going to serve these files?

Comment: I have a separate media server which hosts those file.

Answer (score 0):

a) File upload call: This is very subjective.. depending on the situation. What is the facade doing ? Is it only re-directing requests to right micro-service ? Many a times when there is a grey line; I always prefer design which gives me better performance. If adding extra hop not giving me any flexibility; I will avoid it.

b) Here I can give you a definitive answer. Always every micro-service should be self-contained. We do not know who will be calling our service in future.. We should never code it assuming one particular client. Hence, all the validations should be part of our micro-service. Here exception can be authentication service; for which sometimes we have independent micro-service but even token verification should happen in individual micro-service.

c) There is not defined design pattern for this.

Comment: For point a), facade is acting as aggregator. It calls n services , aggregates the response and send the final response to user.

Comment: so you are saying facade is a single point of contact for ALL your REST endpoints.. This is right design anyway..

Comment: So should I call file upload from facade or individual service?

Comment: In order to maintain consistency; UI should call facade which should in turn call Microservice.. Make sure that calling is on Internal IP address and not using public IP to reduce latency between different services and between facade and micro service.